# object variable or with block variable not set on excel macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

i try to create button to add data with looping on last row, but i got error with code "object variable or with block variable not set"

here is my code

```
Sub Add_Click2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim emptyRow1 As Long
Dim Celltujuan2 As Range

Set Menu = Sheets("Interface")
Set Db2 = Sheets("Database CMMS")

'DB Power
Db2.Activate
RCNumberCMMS = Menu.Range("D20").Value
Set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=RCNumberCMMS)

If RCNumberCMMS = "" Then
MsgBox ("Silakan isi RC Number terlebih Dahulu!")
Exit Sub
End If


Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Info
For i = 25 To 35
Cells(Celltujuan2, Menu.Range("E" & i).Value) = Menu.Range("D" & i).Value
Next i

'DOP & Approval
For i = 25 To 34
Cells(Celltujuan2, Menu.Range("I" & i).Value) = Menu.Range("H" & i).Value
Next i


'Install & Material Eks
For i = 25 To 33
Cells(Celltujuan2, Menu.Range("M" & i).Value) = Menu.Range("L" & i).Value
Next i

'Write Off
For i = 25 To 26
Cells(Celltujuan2, Menu.Range("Q" & i).Value) = Menu.Range("P" & i).Value
Next i

MsgBox ("Data Telah Terupdate")


Menu.Activate
Menu.Range("D20").Select

End Sub
```

i do the same code for other sheet and running well,
i create this code in the same workbook but in diffren module, is that the problem ?

Comment: `Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1` needs to be `set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Also `Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1` returns a number, which isn't compatible with a range variable.

Comment: Hy Christofer, any suggest for row number that isn't compatible with a range variable ?

Comment: Your code does not make sense. First you

    `Set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=RCNumberCMMS)`

Then you try to overwrite the same variable 

    `Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

It is very unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You could set the number to a number variable `lRow = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1` and then set the range `Set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A" & lrow)` I guess?

Comment: Actually I believe you should replace `Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1` with `emptyRow1 = Db2.Range("A" & Db2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: `Cells(Celltujuan2, Menu.Range("I" & i).Value) = Menu.Range("H" & i).Value` Also looks suspicious. `Cells(Range, number)` isn't valid? Oh, wait I guess Celltujuan2 shouldn't be a range after all, the second time.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber With `Set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=RCNumberCMMS)` the variable `Celltujuan2` is set to a range. With `Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1` he writes the row number to the value of that range (nothing wrong here). Then he uses the value of this cell in `Cells(Celltujuan2,` because the range `Celltujuan2` defaults to `Celltujuan2.Value`. So it is not `Cells(Range, number)` but `Cells(number, number)` and correct. The issue is that if `Find` fails to find something then `Celltujuan2` is `Nothing` therefore the error.

Comment: Right, the real problem is that `If RCNumberCMMS = "" Then` should be `If Celltujuan2 Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @ChristoferWeber no actually the `If RCNumberCMMS = "" Then` has nothing to do with `If Celltujuan2 Is Nothing Then` that doesn't need to be replaced, that is a completly independent test. Just add the test for `If Celltujuan2 Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 1):

After using `Find` you need to check if something was found.

```
Set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=RCNumberCMMS)
If Celltujuan2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox """" & RCNumberCMMS & """ was not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If you read the documentation of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) it says:

> The settings for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

So you need to specify at least those parameters or something random is used (there is no default).

```
Set Celltujuan2 = Db2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=RCNumberCMMS, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)
If Celltujuan2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox """" & RCNumberCMMS & """ was not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
```